# Are statistics accumulated across multiple check-sats?

Tags: z3

Are the numbers returned by `(get-info :all-statistics)` accumulated across multiple calls to `check-sat`, and across multiple `push`-`pop` scopes? Or are they reset at each `check-sat` (or at `push` or `pop`)?

Phrased differently, if I get statistics at various points during a run of Z3, and if a certain statistics, e.g.`quant-instantiations` always has the same value, can I then conclude that no quantifier instantiation happened in between getting these statistics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a quick search and it appears that no `obj::reset_statistics()` is called between check-sat calls for various `obj`s. There are a few re-initializations happening though, so no guarantee that any of this is precise enough for your purpose.